# Create a dummy variable from Categorical Dummy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable that have values from 0 to 22 and I want to create a variables for Support Vector Machine, that split this data as follow:

0: Including values from 0 to 12;

1: Including values from 13 to 22.

How can I generate a dummy from this variable?

I'm using pandas and sklearn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df['dummy_medianrat'] = df['Column with your variable'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < 13 else 1)
```

Comment: I applied your code (variable is "median_rating"), but it show me only output witouth create a new coloumn with these new variables.
I want to generate a new coloumns called for example "dummy_medianrat"

Comment: @GiovanniPontonio I've edited the code to create the new column